# Section Number Counter for All Figures included

Tags: counters

What rules should be used if all theorems, figures, definitions, observations and lemmas are to use a continuous counter for the individual section only.

Comment: Each of these environments with its own counter?

Comment: sorry @bernard, all one counter for each section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `figure` counter to change with section and declare all your theorem structure to use the `figure` counter. If you want these counters to be prefixed by the section counter, use  `\counterwithin` in the place of `\counterwithin*`.:

```
\documentclass[l]{article}
\usepackage{xcharter}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}%
\usepackage{mathtools, chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}[figure]{Theorem}%
\newtheorem{lemma}[figure]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[figure]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}

\begin{defn}
  A simple definition
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
  The following assertion is true: %
  \[ a = a\]%
\end{thm}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{myfig}
  \caption{A figure}\label{Afig}
\end{figure}

\begin{lemma}
  The following assertion is true: %
  \begin{equation}\label{testeq}
    a = a\end{equation}
    \end{lemma}

    \section{Another lovely section}
    \begin{defn}
      A simple definition
    \end{defn}

    \begin{thm}
      The following assertion is true: %
      \[ b\,a = ba\]%
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how would you change this such that it was definition 1.1 for section 1 ect

Comment: Use `\counterwithin` (no star) instead. Please see my updated answer.