# Single counter per section

Tags: numbering

I'd like to achieve this same behavior: [Section Number Counter for All Figures included](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344535/section-number-counter-for-all-figures-included)
but also for subsections. For instance:

```
1. First section
1.1 Subsection
1.2 Figure
1.3 Theorem
1.4 Another subsection
2. Second section
2.1. Subsection
2.2. Another theorem
```

I have tried several approaches based on what I've read in this website, but so far I didn't manage to produce this kind of counter. Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want your `theorem` and `figure` counter to be exactly like that of `subsection`. Consider `\dupcntr{figure}{subsection} \dupcntr{theorem}{subsection}` from [Slave duplicate counter](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764) (possible duplicate). Or use [`xassoccnt`](//ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt)'s functionality.

Comment: if you do this you should disable all floats; it would not make sense to number floating figures in the same sequence as non floating subsections and theorems as the numbers will appear out of order

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner, that did the job!